# My timer in cloud function stop after the second call

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My app is a multi-player game in which the player can create a session, each session has a unique `sessionID` and contains many rounds, and each round has its own timer.

I did a cloud function for implementing a timer. It works well, but if `session1` starts its timer and then `session2` starts its own timer. What happens is the timer in `session1` stops!

The function I wrote it by javascript, and it updates the timer in a real-time database in firebase every second.

[image: structure my real-time database]

the cloud function code

```
exports.RoundTimerS = functions.database.ref('/Sessions/{sessionid}/onCamera')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    var SessionID = context.params.sessionid
    sessionref4 = "/Sessions/".concat(SessionID);
    sessionref4 = sessionref4.concat("/Timer");

    sessionref5 = "/Sessions/".concat(SessionID);
    sessionref5 = sessionref5.concat("/numOfPlayers");

    sessionref6 = "/Sessions/".concat(SessionID);
    sessionref6 = sessionref6.concat("/NumberOfFinish");

    Roundtimer = 60 //60s
 
    var player = 0
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref(sessionref5); 
    var ref2 = db.ref(sessionref6);

    ref.once("value", function (snapshot2) {
        player = snapshot2.val() 
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

    var Timer = setInterval(function () {
        admin.database()
            .ref(sessionref4 + "/Roundtimer1").set(Roundtimer)
        ref2.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.numChildren() == player) {                   
                clearInterval(Timer)//Stop timer 
            }
        }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });

        if (Roundtimer <= 0) { //Round Timer finish 
            admin.database()
                .ref(sessionref4 + "/Roundtimer1").set(Roundtimer) 
            clearInterval(Timer)//Stop timer 
        }

        Roundtimer -= 1
```

Comment: Running a timer like this in the database is quite inefficient, and not necessary. For a much simpler way to run timers across clients, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843397/how-to-implement-a-distributed-countdown-timer-in-firebase

Comment: I see it, I need to set the timer in real-time so the user can observe the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions run until the final `}` of their code, which is well before your timer is finished. So your container gets recycled before the timer finished.

If you want the container to stay alive for any asynchronous operations, you need to return a promise that resolves once all work is done.

```
exports.RoundTimerS = functions.database.ref('/Sessions/{sessionid}/onCamera')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var SessionID = context.params.sessionid
    sessionref4 = "/Sessions/".concat(SessionID);
    sessionref4 = sessionref4.concat("/Timer");

    sessionref5 = "/Sessions/".concat(SessionID);
    sessionref5 = sessionref5.concat("/numOfPlayers");

    sessionref6 = "/Sessions/".concat(SessionID);
    sessionref6 = sessionref6.concat("/NumberOfFinish");

    Roundtimer = 60 //60s
 
    var player = 0
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref(sessionref5); 
    var ref2 = db.ref(sessionref6);

    ref.once("value", function (snapshot2) {
        player = snapshot2.val() 
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

    var Timer = setInterval(function () {
        db.ref(sessionref4 + "/Roundtimer1").set(Roundtimer)
        ref2.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.numChildren() == player) {                   
                clearInterval(Timer)//Stop timer 
            }
        }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });

        if (Roundtimer <= 0) { //Round Timer finish 
            db.ref(sessionref4 + "/Roundtimer1").set(Roundtimer).then(() =
> {
              resolve(); // this seems to be where your timer is done
            })
            clearInterval(Timer)//Stop timer 
        }

        Roundtimer -= 1
        ...
  });
```

Note that this is **not** meant to be a copy/paste solution, but rather an outline of the approach you should take. Which is:

1. Return a promise.
2. Resolve that the the work is done.

I highly recommend reading up on asynchronous work in Cloud Functions, as you'll keep running into problems until you've got that under control. Some good resources:

- The documentation on [Sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)
- Doug's video series on [Learn JavaScript Promises with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA)