# How to implement a distributed countdown timer with Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

So basically I'm running an online game site whereby each "match" would be a certain duration, after said duration the "match" would change in name and details. How do I implement a live countdown which synchronizes with all users, which continues running on the server side even when a user closes the window?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a distributed counter for this. The timestamp you need is *state*, and state should be managed by the game server.

In Firebase (or Firestore) you can implement this functionality with a **snapshot listener**. Each client would then subscribe to this listener. See this question for an example:
[How to implement a distributed countdown timer in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843397/how-to-implement-a-distributed-countdown-timer-in-firebase).

Also, you might find useful this thread on Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/mnitde/making_a_timer_for_a_tabletop_game_in_firebase/