# How to Create a Firebase Server Side Timer in Android App With background Functionality in Android Studio using java?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, countdowntimer

I am trying to create Online Spin Earning App. So i wish i set a timer in my app so when users Spin Life  is ended a 24 hour timer will start and i want to create this using Firebase Server Side Timer in Android App Which also run in background even when user turn off the phone or close the app. I am using Android Studio and Java Anyone Please help me i need yours help

Create a Firebase Server Side Timer in Android App With background functionality

Comment: There is no way to run your code on the user's phone if they close the app. The Android OS actively works against that. If the timer is always for 24 hours, you can just record its start and interval, instead of waiting for its end. Also: what needs to happen when that timer expires? In its current form this is just too broad to answer succinctly, but I recommend reading about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Ban  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66843397

Comment: I also think it's a little too broad to reasonably answer, here on Stackoverflow. Can you please be more specific?