# Flutter: Build a Real-Time Counter and Saving the Result on Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, counter

I was wondering how to build a real-time counter that would increase every seconds for a duration of 24 hours.

An example is provided below based on an existing application.

I would like to be able to save the result on Firebase and to use the saved result as a starter point for future incrementations.

In the end, I would like to multiply it by a specific rate maybe using cloud functions, but I think that I can handle this part on my own.

[image]

Does anyone know where should I start ?

Many thanks in advance!

__

I actually build something alike but it is not dynamic as I would expect it to be.

For user experience purpose I would like the counter to be dynamic and to increase until a certain daily amount e.g. 100U for 24h.

Comment: Are you looking for [How to implement a distributed countdown timer in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843397/how-to-implement-a-distributed-countdown-timer-in-firebase)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe that the code I have got so far does not make practical sense as far as it's just showing data from Firebase e.g. 50Units. It is not dynamic and it is updated if the user click on a button after the 24h delay has passed - otherwise nothing happen and the amount remain 50Units.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not really... I am looking for something like this:
-  User click on a button => this starts the counter upward

Let's assume that I want to increase my balance by 50U. In a a day there are 86400 seconds. This means that I would like my counter to increase by 0.000579 every seconds and to stop at the end of the 24h period. 

Then, I want this 50 amount to be written on firebase either at the very beginning or at the end of the 24h period of time (does not matter). I just want to show this incrementation on user's screens. Am I clearer?