# how to make timers for flutter web apps, which can run in the background on browsers?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web-browser

we are building a web application with flutter, and we have run into issues with timers.

In short for each user online, we run timers of different lengths (typically 25 min) the problem is that if you have multiple browser windows open. The timer runs slowly and or shuts off.
Do any of you bright heads have any suggestions on how to combat this browser issue?
BTW we are running on firbase hosting and data bases

Im thinking that we must build a small server application that handles the timers on a dedicated server. And then stream the data to the site. (But this seems like such a hack, and makes me think that we should have built a python or php solution instead)

I could really use some advice here, any ideas?

We tried building it like client based app and using firbase realtime database to update the timers.
And it works fine if the browser window is open and active. The problem is that it is supposed to run in the background and give you a warning sound when done.

Comment: Something like this you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843397/how-to-implement-a-distributed-countdown-timer-in-firebase?

Comment: yes. that might work, we are doing something similar. i will look into it. thanks