# How can I send string data to firebase in background each 50 seconds

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, isolate

I am using counter that increases by 1 every 5 seconds and I want to store its value in firestore.
I need a way to send the data in background and I want you to tell me the best practise to send the counter value and fetch it ? in which lifecycle part should I use the method?
thank you all and I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Not on *my* phone you're not! This is a battery killer, and will likely be rejected by the stores out-right.

Comment: what is the solution in your opinion??

Comment: You can't.  Background processes are killed on Android after a short period.  Tell us what you're actually using the data for, and we can probably tell you a better way to do it.  For example, if the counter increases by 1 every 5s, you can just write the current value and time, and calculate how many seconds have passed since that time the next time you read it, and adjust the value

Comment: @GabeSechan  I want to calculate the time that the user is staying on my app and give him one point each 5 seconds.
so I had to store this values in my firestore.
any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the counter increases by 1 every 5 seconds, there is no need to update the document every 5 seconds. All you need is to store is the moment the counter started, as everything else can be derived from that on the client.

For an example of how to implement such a distributed timer, see [How to implement a distributed countdown timer in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843397/how-to-implement-a-distributed-countdown-timer-in-firebase). While this question is using Firebase's other database, the same approach can be applied to Firestore.

Comment: I want to calculate the time that the user is spending on the app

Comment: In that case the counter shouldn't increase while the app is backgrounded, as the user isn't spending time in the app. --- You might in general want to consider using a tool like Google Analytics for this type of functionality, as it's more fitted for the job.