# Update Firebase RealTime while reading in Interval causes the number flicking

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, svelte

I am working on a SvelteKit countdown timer with Firebase RealTime DB for syncing the countdown across different browsers, I have my code based on [How to implement a distributed countdown timer in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843397/how-to-implement-a-distributed-countdown-timer-in-firebase/77345972#77345972).

​

Summarize my question:

How can I fix my issue when I read the doc in an interval and update the doc with the state that could be refreshed so the numbers won't flick?

while addTen mins I have set my firebase with a new value (update also causes the same problem), and the console.log() ran twice if I didn't refresh my page, thank you very much for taking the time to answer it!

I have created a custom store for unsubscribe onValue from FireBase, which works fine but the addTen mins function causes some problems.

[image]

```js
    const fbUnsubscribe = onValue(currentRef, (snapshot) => {
        const current = snapshot.val();
        const { remaining, startAt } = current;

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            let timeLeft = remaining - (Date.now() - startAt - serverTimeOffset) / (60 * 1000);

            if (timeLeft < 0 || isNaN(timeLeft)) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                clearBooking();
            } else {
                // console.log(timeLeft);
                timeLeft -= 1;
                update(() => timeLeft);
            }
            console.log(remaining, new Date().getSeconds());
        }, 1000);
    });

    const addTen = () => {
        get(child(ref(firebaseDB), currentPath)).then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const current = snapshot.val();
                console.log(current);
                fbSet(currentRef, {
                    ...current,
                    remaining: current.remaining + 10
                });
            } else {
                console.error('No document found.');
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: The function passed to `onValue()` runs every time there's a value change. This means you're starting a new interval every time something changes

Comment: ok, thanks I think I got what you mean, are there any ways to prevent it? At the first, I thought it was a frontend state issue, or I should use get() instead of onValue()?

Comment: Can't really tell without knowing what `clearBooking()` and `update()` do

Comment: `clearBooking()` is setting the remaining back to 0,
`update()` is the updating the svelte store, the store got updated twice in the interval, does that mean I should `clearInterval()` when I try to `addTen()`?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone is the future searching for an answer.
if you are using Svelte, you can run the `onValue` in the `onMount(){}`, but you **must** do `onDestroy(){}` to `clearInterval()` to prevent a memory leak.

```js
let interval;
let unsubscribe;
onMount(){ 
// your firebase unsubscribe goes here.
    unsubscribe = onValue(......, 
    interval = setInterval(()=> {....}, 1000))
}
onDestroy(){
  unsubscribe; 
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

For my situation which I need to update the record while reading, it started glitching because the `setInterval()` ran everytime I changed (as mentioned in the comment section above), to deal with the glitching, you can `clearInterval(interval [or your intervalId])` if you are trying to update the property in the Firebase Realtime Database while using `onValue()` in the `setInterval()`;

There could be a potential for a memory leak, which I haven't found a solution to yet.